# Mathematical functions - drawing issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to develop a function plotter where the user can enter up to 10 different polynomial or trigonometrical functions. Each function is represented by a polyline and is drawn on a canvas. All the functions are stored in an observable collection of functions. However, if I keep adding more and more functions, they don't show up at the right place. In the following pictures I tried to add the same function over and over again but it keeps placing them on the bottom of each other.

[image]

[image]

To draw the functions I use this code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Functions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Polyline Points="{Binding Output, Converter={StaticResource pointConverter}}" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" Stroke="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default itemspanel of an itemscontrol is a stackpanel.

You don't seem to have changed that.

Try adding the below to your itemscontrol.

```
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Canvas        ClipToBounds="True"
                        IsItemsHost="True" 
                        />
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to delete the "ClipToBounds" and "IsItemsHost" from your suggestion but that works fine so far. :)